# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql

Tags: java, java-9, ojdbc

I have a jar generated with jdk 1.6, it's working fine with jdk 1.7 and 1.7 but I get the following exception when trying to run it with 1.9 :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.sql
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:57)
```

my main class :

```
package eai_principale;

import com.siebel.data.SiebelException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MainExecute
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws SQLException, SiebelException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
  {
    System.out.println("-----------------START EAI CONNECTOR EXECUTION------------------");
    Principale execute = new Principale();

    String ligneId = args[0];
    String path = args[1];

    execute.execute(ligneId, path);

    System.out.println("-----------------END EAI CONNECTOR EXECUTION------------------");
  }
}
```

Could you help me ?
I am using Eclipse, and I am using jdbc lib .
Thx

Comment: which version of ojdbc are you using(if I want to reproduce the issue) and for what purposes(to know if there can be some other resort)?

Comment: I use ojdbc 4.0 (for 11.2.0.4.0) to do operations on aracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Eclipse JDT, specifically in the `jarinjarloader` part. It is referenced as [Bug 525885 - jarinjarloader with jdbc jar does not work in jre9](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525885) in Eclipse Bugzilla.

The bugzilla article suggests that using a standard MANIFEST could be a workaround:

> The thing is that my jar will execute in jre9 if I manually remove the jarinjarloader portion and use a standard MANIFEST file.

Comment: I've found the article but I don't know how to  use a standard MANIFEST file instead of jarinjarloader portion. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In my jar, the MANIFEST.MF contains : Manifest-Version: 1.0

Comment: I differ in opinion from the suggested workaround and would really give a try to finding if any of the included jars actually are bringing a similar package. Also, the bug linked doesn't seem like an accepted one to me. Seems Open yet on the reporter. @KnowledgeSeeker could you update the question with a reproducible sample?

Comment: thx for your response but I don't know what you mean by reproductible sample ? for your question, in META-INF\services\ of the ojdbc I have the file : java.sql.Driver , it contains : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
I wonder if I can remove it